# Update Ansible 1.9.4 to Ansible 2.0

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have uninstall ansible 1.9.4 and install with `sudo apt-get install ansible`, the version 2.0.2. 
But when I execute:

```
ikerlan$ ansible --version
ansible 1.9.4
```

I have uninstall and reinstall using ansible ppa, when I install I can see this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../ansible_2.0.0.2-1ppa~trusty_all.deb ...
Unpacking ansible (2.0.0.2-1ppa~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Configurando ansible (2.0.0.2-1ppa~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
```

But if I check ansible version:

```
ikerlan@ikerlan-docker:~$ ansible --version
    ansible 1.9.4
      configured module search path = None
```

If I run the next:

```
ikerlan@ikerlan-docker:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep ansible
ii  ansible                                               2.0.0.2-1ppa~trusty                                 all          A radically simple IT automation platform
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Run `print -rl -- ${(ko)commands} | grep ansible` - do you get more than 1 result? Source - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120818/28596

Comment: If I run the next command: 'print -rl -- ${(ko)commands} | grep ansible', I can see the next: bash: ${(ko)commands}: wrong replacement @Ash

Comment: My mistake, that command is for `zsh`. For `bash` try `compgen -c | grep ansible`.

Comment: Okey Thanks, I can see 12 results:                                               1.ansible | 
2.ansible-galaxy |
3. ansible-pull |
4. ansible-doc |
5.ansible-playbook |
6.ansible-vault |
7.ansible |
8.ansible-galaxy |
9.ansible-pull |
10.ansible-doc |
11 ansible-playbook |
12. ansible-vault   | I can see duplicated 'ansible' two times, is it normal? @Ash

Comment: Right so we have `ansible` twice. That to me indicates that they are not in order you expect so the wrong version is being used when you attempt to execute. Run - which  `compgen -c` | grep ansible - which will give you the full path to - ansible - Feel free to edit your answer with this information as it will be easier than formatting in a comment.

Comment: If I run: ikerlan@ikerlanKVM:~$ which compgen -c | grep ansible -which
The result is: 0  (There appears a zero). Am I putting ok? Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't formatting the command correctly it's http://pastebin.com/RnkTnrNi

Comment: I can see both ansible in the same path, both are /usr/local/bin/ansible. when I acces to /usr/local/bin only appears one ansible. @Ash

Comment: Looks like your `1.9.4` was installed by hand, not via a package, so installing a newer package left its files in place.

Comment: I have installed ansible 1.9.4 using the next command:  *Ubuntu$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 *Ubuntu$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
 *Ubuntu$ sudo apt-get update
 *Ubuntu$ sudo apt-get install ansible @CharlesDuffy

Comment: If that's the case, dpkg should be able to tell you the name of the packages owning the old files so you can uninstall them (those packages, that is)..

Comment: What version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 @Ash

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but what can I do with dpkg? and how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: @Asier, `dpkg-query -S /path/to/file` tells you which package owns a file. If running that on the ansible binary returned by `type ansible` tells you that it's a 1.9.x package, then you have your answer. The trickier case is if you have a newer ansible binary using an *older* library (which is presumably earlier in the Python search path); in that case, you'll want to ask the Python interpreter where it's getting that library from, and *then* use `dpkg-query` to find out which package (if any) owns it.

Comment: @Asier, ...in general, finding out where on disk a Python library is coming from (so you can then ask `dpkg-query` which package owns it) looks something like `python -c 'import ansible; print ansible.__file__'`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I execute 'dpkg-query -S /path/to/file' It appears a lot of python files. example: ansible: /usr/share/pyshared/ansible/playbook/handler.py
ansible: /usr/share/pyshared/ansible/modules/core/network/basics/uri.py

Comment: There's your answer -- those files are provided by the `ansible` package.

Comment: Thanks very much @CharlesDuffy finally I removed all the files of ansible and I reinstall ansible, and its works perfectly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no guarantee you get the latest version just because you uninstalled and reinstalled. As of now Ansible 2.0 is available only through PPA.

[Ansible 2.0 Install](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu)

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ansible
```

Comment: I have tryed this solution but I see ansible 1.9.4, I uninstall ansible and I install using the commands you send me, but ansible version don't change. You can see in the description what I do. @helloV

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep ansible`?

Comment: I have put the output in the description, it says: ansible 2.0.0.2-1ppa~trusty

Answer (score 21):

Here is the right way to upgrade it. Even after installing ansible correctly does not change the version. The solution i found here works nicely.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/eCtBp2aDtCQ

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade ansible
```

Just running this command upgrades and fixes the version too which we check using ansible --version

It will upgrade to latest like now its 2.1

Answer (score 8):

Most like you have actually at some point installed ansible twice - once via PIP and once via apt-get

if you 
`sudo apt-get remove ansible`
and
`sudo pip uninstall ansible`

then run

`compgen -c | grep ansible`

You should not have any results.

And then install from the PPA to get version 2

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ansible
```

run e.g.

`ansible-playbook --version`

and you should now see

`ansible-playbook 2.0.2.0`

Comment: Worked like a charm. THANK YOU!

Comment: what if I still have a list of results after 'compgen...' even if the two first commands return 'ansible not installed'?

Comment: I guess it depends what those results are...but it sounds like you uninstalling failed for some reason.  Or perhaps there's some 3rd way of installing ansible you've done in the past that needs yet another uninstall method?  Not sure on that, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

you can upgrade a single package using

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade ansible
```

or purge the previous packages and config file using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ansible
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then install from ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```